# Get element by attribute name - Angular testing

Tags: angular, angular8

Say, I have following HTML in my Angular component

```
<div name='my-name'>
  something
</div>
```

In my test cases how can I get the above element by attribute `name='my-name'` using `ComponentFixture`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
const debugElement = fixture.debugElement;
const attributeEl = debugElement.query(By.css('div[name="my-name"]'));
```

and make sure to import **By** from `import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';`

Answer (score -1):

try like this

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
debugElement = fixture.debugElement;

const value = debugElement.query(By.css('name='my-name''));
```

if this does not work, let me know.

Comment: please do not add an answer without verifying yourself first.